# Objects on C/C++?

Tags: c++, object

I'm a C# Coder. In C# We can easily pass generic objects to functions, But C++ Doesn't have any definition for objects, Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
void PrintToConsole(object msg)
{
    gameconsole << msg;
}
```

But sadly there's no `object` in C++ as I tried.

My question is, How could I make a function with ability to use any object on It without creating overloads.

Comment: What was your question?

Comment: In C++, you define your own types, and there is no common base-type. But you can use templates to write generic code.

Comment: Are you asking about the lack of generic "base" class that everything inherits from? You can build that yourself.

Comment: You could build that yourself, but that is bad advice.

Comment: "put objects on voids"? "C++ doesn't have any definition for objects"? You're saying things that sound like words, but I have no idea what they mean.

Comment: It's called a "function", not a "void". The `void` keyword means it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I believe your edit is incorrect, original question was referring to the hierarchy in C#, where everything inherits from System.Object. As it stands now the question is more nonsense than it was earlier IMO.

Comment: @CasperVonB: All I did was replace "void" with "function"; and add the word "generic" to make it a bit clearer that function was supposed to take any kind of object (e.g. via C#'s magic base class), not some specific kind. I'm not sure why you think that makes it nonsensical.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The question is already nonsense/unclear. However my point was the use of the word generic here might be confusing. As any good answer would involve templates on the C++ side. It's easy to make the assumption that he is asking about C# generics.

Comment: @CasperVonB: OK, if you can think of a word that means "generic" but won't be confused with the C#-specific meaning of that word, then feel free to edit. There's no point having an argument about it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I couldn't, hence the comment rather than an edit ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no universal base class in C++. But you could use templates to generate the same function for every type.

```
template <typename T>
void PrintToConsole(const T& msg) {
    gameconsole << msg;
}
```